# How to create servicenow request item through mail

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

create servicenow request through mail.

I tried to create Incident from my mail box sending a mail to servicenow mail id but i need to know how we can create service-now request item ticket through mail?

Below is the mail i used and incident created successfully but how to do for request item ticket?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since catalog requests are a bit more complicated than Incidents (they're comprised of multiple records like sc_request, sc_req_item, etc.), it's probably best to use the Service Catalog Script API to create the request in your Inbound Action's script:

https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/paris-application-development/page/script/server-scripting/reference/r_ServiceCatalogScriptAPI.html